# Javascript logical "!==" operator?

Tags: javascript, syntax, logical-operators

I am getting back into web development, and have been trying to go over the nuances of jscript recently. I was pouring through the source of the THREEx extension library built on top of Three.JS and noticed this function

```
THREEx.KeyboardState.prototype.pressed  = function(keyDesc)
{
    var keys    = keyDesc.split("+");
    for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
        var key     = keys[i];
        var pressed;
        if( THREEx.KeyboardState.MODIFIERS.indexOf( key ) !== -1 ){
            pressed = this.modifiers[key];
        }else if( Object.keys(THREEx.KeyboardState.ALIAS).indexOf( key ) != -1 ){
            pressed = this.keyCodes[ THREEx.KeyboardState.ALIAS[key] ];
        }else {
            pressed = this.keyCodes[key.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0)];
        }
        if( !pressed)   return false;
    };
    return true;
}
```

I am looking in particular at the line here:

```
if( THREEx.KeyboardState.MODIFIERS.indexOf( key ) !== -1 ){
```

I am not familiar with this !== operator. I checked w3schools and their logical operators list does not have this one included. I am not sure if this is misspelled and the browsers simply count it as != or if it has some other meaning. Also I was wondering whether this is actually a single logical operator or whether it is some kind of combination, like ! + ==?

Comment: http://w3fools.com

Comment: The [JavaScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) is a useful resource for answering such questions.

Comment: @HenryHenrinson the latest specs (like [this one](https://tc39.es/ecma262/)) are a lot easier to navigate, but I'll agree that the content is extremely dense. However, it does spell out the semantics of everything thoroughly.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can find `===` and `!==` operators in several other dynamically-typed languages as well. It always means that the two values are not only compared by their "implied" value (i.e. either or both values might get converted to make them comparable), but also by their original type.

That basically means that if `0 == "0"` returns true, `0 === "0"` will return false because you are comparing a number and a string. Similarly, while `0 != "0"` returns false, `0 !== "0"` returns true.

Answer (score 22):

It's `!=` without type coercion. See the [MDN documentation for comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

Also see [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/87399), which includes a quote from "JavaScript: The Good Parts" about the problems with `==` and `!=`. (`null == undefined`, `false == "0"`, etc.)

Short answer: *always* use `===` and `!==` unless you have a compelling reason to do otherwise. (Tools like [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/), [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/), [ESLint](http://eslint.org/), etc. will give you this same advice.)

Answer (score 10):

Copied from the formal specification: [ECMAScript 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) section 11.9.5

> #### 11.9.4 The Strict Equals Operator ( === )
>
> The production *EqualityExpression* : *EqualityExpression* === *RelationalExpression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *lref* be the result of evaluating *EqualityExpression*.
> 2. Let *lval* be GetValue(*lref*).
> 3. Let *rref* be the result of evaluating *RelationalExpression*.
> 4. Let *rval* be GetValue(*rref*).
> 5. Return the result of performing the strict equality comparison *rval* === *lval*. (See 11.9.6)
>
> #### 11.9.5 The Strict Does-not-equal Operator ( !== )
>
> The production EqualityExpression : *EqualityExpression* !== *RelationalExpression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *lref* be the result of evaluating *EqualityExpression*.
> 2. Let *lval* be GetValue(*lref*).
> 3. Let *rref* be the result of evaluating *RelationalExpression*.
> 4. Let *rval* be GetValue(*rref*).
>      Let *r* be the result of performing strict equality comparison *rval* === *lval*. (See 11.9.6)
> 5. If *r* is **true**, return **false**. Otherwise, return **true**.
>
> #### 11.9.6 The Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm
>
> The comparison *x* === *y*, where *x* and *y* are values, produces **true** or **false**. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> 1. If Type(*x*) is different from Type(*y*), return **false**.
> 2. Type(*x*) is Undefined, return **true**.
> 3. Type(*x*) is Null, return **true**.
> 4. Type(*x*) is Number, then
>
>    1. If *x* is NaN, return **false**.
>    2. If *y* is NaN, return **false**.
>    3. If *x* is the same Number value as *y*, return **true**.
>    4. If *x* is +0 and y is -0, return **true**.
>    5. If *x* is -0 and y is +0, return **true**.
>    6. Return **false**.
> 5. If Type(*x*) is String, then return **true** if *x* and *y* are exactly the same sequence of characters (same length and same characters in corresponding positions); otherwise, return **false**.
> 6. If Type(*x*) is Boolean, return **true** if *x* and y are both **true** or both **false**; otherwise, return **false**.
> 7. Return **true** if *x* and *y* refer to the same object. Otherwise, return **false**.

Answer (score 4):

The `!==` opererator tests whether values are not equal or not the same type.
i.e.

```
var x = 5;
var y = '5';
var 1 = y !== x; // true
var 2 = y != x; // false
```

Answer (score 2):

reference [here](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/comparison_operators.html)

!== is the strict not equal operator and only returns a value of true if both the operands are not equal and/or not of the same type. The following examples return a Boolean true:

```
a !== b 
a !== "2" 
4 !== '4'
```

Answer (score 0):

`!==`

> This is the strict not equal operator and only returns a value of true
>   if both the operands are not equal and/or not of the same type. The
>   following examples return a Boolean true:

```
a !== b
a !== "2"
4 !== '4'
```